# android - what devices support which sensors

Tags: android, hardware, android-sensors, temperature

I am looking for a list of which devices support which sensors, specifically, the `TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE` sensor.

which devices support this sensor? and is there a list?

Comment: There are several thousand Android device models. I am not aware of anyone keeping a list of all the models, let alone which ones support which sensors.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better request list of supported sensors programmatically like:

```
SensorManager sensorsManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
List<Sensor> sensors = sensorsManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
for (Sensor sensor : sensors) 
    Log.d("Sensors", "" + sensor.getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can interrogate your device to see what it supports. Personally, I've not run it on one that thinks it has temperature, but it is device/maker specific